# All links don't work & mobile menu missing after installing featherbox gallery! Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

Here's the [link](http://ciadgroup.com/resport/index.html) for you to take a look for yourself.

For the life of me, I don't understand why my website (only on this page) has gone so limp.

All links do not work, except for the home and contact the non expandable ones.)

The nav menu is gone as well.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware of the console errors?

Comment: there are issues with your Residential page within portfolio... check those errors, once you click that page it renders your nav useless

Comment: These errors are extremely odd..They should not mess with the functionality of the site, should they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading 2 versions of jQuery, 1.7 and 1.11 and you have an error the order of your config.js loading. First remove the old version of jQuery and then move all your scripts to the bottom of the page in an order like this:

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
<script src="featherlight.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="featherlight.gallery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
  <script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.gallery').featherlightGallery({
                gallery: {
                    fadeIn: 300,
                    fadeOut: 300
                },
                openSpeed:    300,
                closeSpeed:   300
            });
            $('.gallery2').featherlightGallery({
                gallery: {
                    next: 'next »',
                    previous: '« previous'
                },
                variant: 'featherlight-gallery2'
            });
        });

        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js','ga');
    </script>
```